# c# double.parse() to always use a . period not comma

Tags: c#, decimal

How can I specify that my decimal.Parse must always expect to receive a string with a '.' like "4.75" no mater what the system settings of the computer are?

I am reading in a file from excel and it gives me value with a '.' and I see that if I run my program on my laptop It throws and error as it expects a ','

I can use:

```
string tmp1 = tmp[2].Replace('.', ',');
```

but then obviously if my computer wants a ''. then it will give an error.

What is my best option?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See: [`Double.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ebt447.aspx)

Use this overload to specify an `IFormatProvider` in your case [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx).

```
var value = double.Parse(tmp[2], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

However I would recommend [`Double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw.aspx) if you intend to make your process durable.

```
double value;

if(!double.TryParse(tmp[2],
   NumberStyles.None,
   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
   out value))
{
    // error handling
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`Double.Parse Method (String, IFormatProvider)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/t9ebt447.aspx) with  `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` for parsing.

```
double d = double.Parse("2.2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the overload of [Decimal.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7xswkc6.aspx) which will allow you to specify a culture:

```
decimal value = decimal.Parse(tmp[2], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```